# Why Gemfile install gem even though group switch set to :production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When I configure Gemfile like this, and then runs "bundle install" in local environment, bundle install 'pg' even though group switch is set.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

My expectation is not to install 'pg' when local.
Despite of my expectation, Gemfile.lock turns to this.

```
  net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.9)
    nokogiri (1.15.3-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.1.0)
    public_suffix (5.0.1)
    puma (5.6.6)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.7.1)
    rack (2.2.7)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (7.0.6)

...
DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  capybara
  debug
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  pg (= 1.1)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.0.4, >= 7.0.4.3)
```

*This is snippet.

My env is below.

```
Windows 11 Pro 22H2
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
rails (7.0.4.3)
```

Please let me know why it happens. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it's a bit counterintuitive.

We could know from the [Bundler doc](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-install.1.html#INSTALLING-GROUPS):

> By default, 'bundle install' will install all gems in all groups in your Gemfile.
> However, you can explicitly tell Bundler to skip installing certain groups with the --without option.

So you could use `bundle install --without production` to skip installing `production` group gems.

Or setting a [config](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-config.1.html) so you don't have to add `-without production` option every time.

```
$ bundle config without production
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see your point. Definitely, will do.